# Does Python require intimate knowledge of all classes in the inheritance chain?

Tags: python, subclass, private

Python classes have no concept of public/private, so we are told to not touch something that starts with an underscore unless we created it.  But does this not require complete knowledge of all classes from which we inherit, directly or indirectly?  Witness:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self._foo = 0

    def foo(self):
        return self._foo + 1

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
        self._foo = None

Sub().foo()
```

Expectedly, a `TypeError` is raised when `None + 1` is evaluated.  So I have to know that `_foo` exists in the base class.  To get around this, `__foo` can be used instead, which solves the problem by mangling the name.  This seems to be, if not elegant, an acceptable solution.  However, what happens if `Base` inherits from a class (in a separate package) called `Sub`?  Now `__foo` in my `Sub` overrides `__foo` in the grandparent `Sub`.

This implies that I have to know the entire inheritance chain, including all "private" objects each uses.  The fact that Python is dynamically-typed makes this even harder, since there are no declarations to search for.  The worst part, however, is probably the fact `Base` might inherit from `object` right now, but in some future release, it switches to inheriting from `Sub`.  Clearly if I know `Sub` is inherited from, I can rename my class, however annoying that is.  But I can't see into the future.

Is this not a case where a true private data type would prevent a problem?  How, in Python, can I be sure that I'm not accidentally stepping on somebody's toes if those toes might spring into existence at some point in the future?

*EDIT*: I've apparently not made clear the primary question.  I'm familiar with name mangling and the difference between a single and a double underscore.  The question is: how do I deal with the fact that I might clash with classes *whose existence I don't know of right now*?  If my parent class (which is in a package I did not write) happens to start inheriting from a class with the same name as my class, even name mangling won't help.  Am I wrong in seeing this as a (corner) case that true private members would solve, but that Python has trouble with?

*EDIT*: As requested, the following is a full example:

File `parent.py`:

```
class Sub(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__foo = 12
    def foo(self):
        return self.__foo + 1
class Base(Sub):
    pass
```

File `sub.py`:

```
import parent
class Sub(parent.Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
        self.__foo = None
Sub().foo()
```

The grandparent's `foo` is called, but my `__foo` is used.

Obviously you wouldn't write code like this yourself, but `parent` could easily be provided by a third party, the details of which could change at any time.

Comment: can you post an example to demonstrate this where the other Same named class doesnt entirely shadow your existing Class?..or maybe Im still not understanding..nevermind ... i made one and your right i guess this is a corner case...just try not to use common private var/class names I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This implies that I have to know the entire inheritance chain. . .

Yes, you should know the entire inheritance chain, or the docs for the object you are directly sub-classing should tell you what you need to know.

Subclassing is an advanced feature, and should be treated with care.

A good example of docs specifying what should be overridden in a subclass is the [threading class](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> This class represents an activity that is run in a separate thread of control. There are two ways to specify the activity: by passing a callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the `run()` method in a subclass. No other methods (except for the constructor) should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only override the `__init__()` and `run()` methods of this class.

Answer (score 7):

Use [*private* names](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) (instead of *protected* ones), starting with a double underscore:

```
class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
        self.__foo = None
        #    ^^
```

will not conflict with `_foo` or `__foo` in `Base`. This is because Python replaces the double underscore with a single underscore and the name of the class; the following two lines are equivalent:

```
class Sub(Base):
    def x(self):
        self.__foo = None # .. is the same as ..
        self._Sub__foo = None
```

(In response to the edit:) The chance that two classes in a class hierarchy not only have the same name, but that they are both using the same property name, and are both using the private mangled (`__`) form is so minuscule that it can be safely ignored in practice (I for one haven't heard of a single case so far).

In theory, however, you are correct in that in order to formally verify correctness of a program, one most know the entire inheritance chain. Luckily, formal verification usually requires a fixed set of libraries in any case.

This is in the spirit of the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which includes

> practicality beats purity.

Comment: But would it conflict with a hypothetical `Base.__foo`?

Comment: I think that's worth a special mention in your answer as it is more in line with what the OP seems to ask

Comment: no because of name mangleing that occures with double underscore however you could probably do `self._Base__foo = None` and have the same result as in the OP (at least i think thats how it would be with  the mangling...):P

Comment: I'm aware of double underscores; I noted them in the question.  The problem is when two classes of the same name are part of the inheritance chain.  Mangling won't be helpful there.

Answer (score 3):

1. Name mangling includes the class so your `Base.__foo` and `Sub.__foo` will have different names.  This was the entire reason for adding the name mangling feature to Python in the first place.  One will be `_Base__foo`, the other `_Sub__foo`.
2. Many people prefer to use composition (has-a) instead of inheritance (is-a) for some of these very reasons.

Comment: isnt this wrong?  I thought mangling only occured with double underscores not single...

Comment: I mentioned name mangling; the special case I noted was something like A->B->A (where the first A is obviously in a separate package).  Now the grandparent class mangles things the same way my subclass does, removing the advantage that name mangling provides.

Answer (score 2):

How often do you modify base classes in inheritance chains to introduce inheritance from a class with the same name as a subclass further down the chain???

Less flippantly, yes, you have to know the code you are working with. You *certainly* have to know the public names being used, after all. Python being python, discovering the public names in use by your ancestor classes takes pretty much the same effort as discovering the private ones.

In years of Python programming, I have never found this to be much of an issue in practice. When you're naming instance variables, you should have a pretty good idea whether (a) a name is generic enough that it's likely to be used in other contexts and (b) the class you're writing is likely to be involved in an inheritance hierarchy with other unknown classes. In such cases, you think a bit more carefully about the names you're using; `self.value` isn't a great idea for an attribute name, and neither is something like `Adaptor` a great class name.

In contrast, I have run into difficulties with the overuse of double-underscore names a number of times. Python being Python, even "private" names tend to be accessed by code defined outside the class. You might think that it would always be bad practice to let an external function access "private" attributes, but what about things like `getattr` and `hasattr`? The *invocation* of them can be in the class's own code, so the class is still controlling all access to the private attributes, but they still don't work without you doing the name-mangling manually. If Python had actually-enforced private variables you couldn't use functions like those on them at all. These days I tend to reserve double-underscore names for cases when I'm writing something very generic like a decorator, metaclass, or mixin that needs to add a "secret attribute" to the instances of the (unknown) classes it's applied to.

And of course there's the standard dynamic language argument: the reality is that you have to test your code thoroughly to have much justification in making the claim "my software works". Such testing will be very unlikely to miss the bugs caused by accidentally clashing names. If you are not doing that testing, then *many* more uncaught bugs will be introduced by other means than by accidental name clashes.

In summation, the lack of private variables is just not that big a deal in idiomatic Python code in practice, and the addition of true private variables would cause more frequent problems in other ways IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you can use name mangling. However, you can stick with a single underscore (or none!) if you document your code adequately - you should not have so many private variables that this proves to be a problem. Just say if a method relies on a private variable, and add either the variable, or the name of the method to the class docstring to alert users.

Further, if you create unit tests, you should create tests that check invariants on members, and accordingly these should be able to show up such name clashes.

If you really want to have "private" variables, and for whatever reason name-mangling doesn't meet your needs, you can factor your private state into another object:

```
class Foo(object):

     class Stateholder(object): pass

     def __init__(self):
         self._state = Stateholder()
         self.state.private = 1
```

Comment: The implication is thus that once you write a class, you can never modify how it works, because anybody inheriting from it might have used a name you yourself might use in your modifications?  Unit tests might well be the best way to treat the symptom, if there is no real way to treat the cause.

Comment: @Chris The problem you imagine does not exist in the form you are imagining. The same thing would happen if you introduced a new public name. The solution to that is configuration management, which is a normal part of software development. In any case, this problem only arises if you are creating libraries - if it is within one codebase, just speak to your colleagues.

Comment: That is true in the context of a language that is very loose with the idea of public/private.  A language with a strong distinction between the two would make it easy to have a "stable API, mutable internals" approach; I can get behind an unchanging API much more than unchanging internals.  I consider the lack of such a distinction a problem, but I accept that others do not.

Comment: @Chris The public-private distinction seems to lead to much fruitless pondering about protection levels. It also facilitates very deep inheritance chains because things are "safe". In practice, java ends up with very little in the way of inherited internals, because of single-inheritance, and relies on interfaces instead. By contrast, python has more than one way of creating a truly protected object.

Answer (score 0):

Mangling happens with double underscores.  Single underscores are more of a "please don't".

You don't need to know all the details of all parent classes (note that deep inheritance is usually best avoided), because you can still dir() and help() and any other form of introspection you can come up with.